# How to fix the error /blosom_20190304: Permission denied

Tags: 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu and I need to run a model on it. This model is an oil spill model that the pack of the model contains with dependencies for the version of Linux. When running the model I have got the below errors.

> ./launch_BLOSOM_cmd.sh: 5: ./launch_BLOSOM_cmd.sh:
>   /home/pkhedri/blosom_20190304: Permission denied
>   ./launch_BLOSOM_cmd.sh: 5: cd: can't cd to /data/
>   ./launch_BLOSOM_cmd.sh: 9: ./launch_BLOSOM_cmd.sh:
>   /home/pkhedri/blosom_20190304/BLOSOM: not found

Here is the link of code that I need to install. I was wondering if you could have a look it .
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=10qgckwmewI4VdBJn2p8XA4AdNOHPIBFW

Comment: Try running it as sudo. First type `sudo su` in the terminal. Type your password then try installing it again.

Comment: thanks for your time.I tried this way, but I got that errors again.